# System parameter in catalog tcpip node

Tags: db2

What is the purpose of the "system" parameter when cataloging tcpip nodes?

```
>>-CATALOG--+-------+--+-TCPIP NODE--+--nodename---------------->
            '-ADMIN-'  +-TCPIP4 NODE-+             
                       '-TCPIP6 NODE-'             

>--REMOTE--+-hostname-----+--SERVER--+-service-name-+----------->
           +-IPv4 address-+          '-port number--'   
           '-IPv6 address-'                             

>--+----------------+--+--------------------------------+------->
   +-SECURITY SOCKS-+  '-REMOTE_INSTANCE--instance-name-'   
   '-SECURITY SSL---'                                       

>--+---------------------+--+-------------------------------+--->
   '-SYSTEM--system-name-'  '-OSTYPE--operating-system-type-'   

>--+------------------------+----------------------------------><
   '-WITH--"comment-string"-'
```

What is the difference with "hostname"? I always ignore this value, but I want to know its purpose. Is it just informative? where can I see the effect of including or ignoring it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it gives you an opportunity to supply a human-friendly name for the system if its hostname is not defined or is not informative, such as `d33a891p.z30b.l8.mycompany.com`

Comment: This is correct.  Control Center used this information when it was building the "tree" of systems / instances / databases.